# How to prevent my manytomany relationship from infinte recursion or JSON writing failure?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, many-to-many

I'm trying to make a bidirectional manytomany relationship work with Hibernate and Maven, but it always either throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session or a Stackoverflowerror. I already tried @JSONIdentityInfo ,which resulted in Maven automatically adding a "PK" Variable which disrupted mainly my Frontend, @JSONManagedReference and @JSONBackreference, which caused the entity that received the Backreference to be ignored completly, @JSONIgnore, same issue with the Backreference, @JsonView, which changed seemingly nothing, and @JsonSerialize with a custom serializer, which when implemented also causes problems with the frontend. I also tried wirting the Query myself direclty into the Repository but it caused the same issue. I am really at the end of my abilties and dont know what else to do.

**Node**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import de.sadgmbh.spring.angular.backenddemo.model.AbstractAuditingEntity;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

@Entity
@Table(name = "knotenpunkte")
//@JsonSerialize(using = CustomKnotenpunktSerializer)
public class Knotenpunkt extends AbstractAuditingEntity<Long> {
    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private int knotennr;
    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String strasse;
    @NotNull
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private boolean codierung;
    @NotNull
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private boolean bake;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "knotenpunkt_linie",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "knotenpunkt_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "linie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    Set<Linie> linienSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Line**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import de.sadgmbh.spring.angular.backenddemo.model.AbstractAuditingEntity;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "linien")
//@JsonSerialize(using = CustomLineSerializer.class)
public class Linie extends AbstractAuditingEntity<Long> {
    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String linienNR;
    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "linienSet")
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    private Set<Knotenpunkt> knotenpunktSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Generated Interfaces by Maven**

```
export interface Knotenpunkt extends AbstractAuditingEntity<number> {
    id: number;
    knotennr: number;
    strasse: string;
    codierung: boolean;
    bake: boolean;
    linienSet: Linie[];
}

export interface Linie extends AbstractAuditingEntity<number> {
    id: number;
    linienNR: string;
    knotenpunktSet: Knotenpunkt[];
}

export interface Views {
}

export interface Internal extends Public {
}

export interface Public {
}

export interface JsonSerializer<T> extends JsonFormatVisitable {
    unwrappingSerializer: boolean;
    delegatee: JsonSerializer<any>;
}
```

Comment: Well, you might want to export the nodes without any references to lines (connections) and then export the lines with just the node ids. That might mean you need a custom serializer and deserializer (Jackson might already support that but I'm not aware of it). In order to get all nodes and lines you might want to first collect them all (use sets to break cycles so that you don't process nodes twice). Then export the nodes and lines separately.

Comment: What you'd want is something like this: `{ "nodes": [{ "id": 1, ...}, { "id" : 2, ...}, ...], "lines" : [{"nodes": [1,2, ...]}, ...] }` (maybe even with the outer "nodes" being an object whose properties are the node ids which makes it easier to get the nodes by id without having to iterate or build another map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to add `@Transactional` to the controller. Hope this might help someone.